# Java 8 - Stream, filter and optional

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I have the following code

```
public Player findPlayerByUsername(String username) {
    return players.stream().filter(p -> p.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username))
                  .findFirst().get();
}
```

The problem is, I want it to return `null` if no value is present, how would I go amongst doing that? Because as it stands, that just throws a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: The whole point of using Optional is to avoid using `null` You should consider returning the `Optional<Player>` instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public Player findPlayerByUsername(final String username) {
   return players.stream().filter(p -> p.getUsername().equalsIgnoreCase(username)).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

The `findFirst()` method returns an `Optional<Player>`.

If optional has player object, `optional.get()` will return that object. If object doesn't exist and you want some alternative, give that option in

```
.orElse(new Player()); or .orElse(null)
```

For more details see [Optional Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html) and [Optional tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_optional_class.htm)

Comment: I was thinking of that, should have elaborated, is it possible to do this in 1 line?

Comment: Yes, let me elaborated

Comment: This is a misuse of ´Optional.findFirst()'. The idea is to use the 'Optional' returned by 'findFirst()' instead of returning null and then checking if the player is null or not.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I disagree that `.orElse(null)` is a misuse.  It can certainly be *overused*, but it has legitimate uses -- it is the dual to `Optional.ofNullable()`, where the two form the gateway pair between the nullable world and the optional world.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Put that way, you're absolutely right. ´Misuse´ is a little bit too harsh word. My point was, as you said, that it's overused many times, i.e. in the code after `findFirst()` there are many `if` statements checking if the value returned by the optional is `!= null` to execute some code block, where using `ifPresent(consumer)` would be far more convenient.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I would say that `orElse(null)` is a *code smell*. It's not necessarily wrong, but it might (often?) indicate that something needs to be improved.